# Issues With JNDI in Hibernate Persistence

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate 2nd edition". I am trying to run the source code the book has provided but getting Exceptions. The problem is in the JNDI.

These are the codes and the exceptions:

```
public enum DatabaseProduct {

 // additional code here

    MYSQL(
        new DataSourceConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public void configure(PoolingDataSource ds, String connectionURL) {
                // TODO: MySQL XA support is completely broken, we use the BTM XA wrapper
                //ds.setClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource");
                ds.setClassName("bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.lrc.LrcXADataSource");
                ds.getDriverProperties().put(
                    "url",
                    connectionURL != null
                        ? connectionURL :
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernate?sessionVariables=sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT'"

                );

                ds.getDriverProperties().put("driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            }
        },
        // Yes, this should work with 5.6, no idea why Gail named it 5.7
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect.class.getName()
    );

    public DataSourceConfiguration configuration;
    public String hibernateDialect;

    private DatabaseProduct(DataSourceConfiguration configuration,
                            String hibernateDialect) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.hibernateDialect = hibernateDialect;
    }

    public interface DataSourceConfiguration {

        void configure(PoolingDataSource ds, String connectionURL);
    }
```

Transaction Manager

```
public class TransactionManagerSetup {

    public static final String DATASOURCE_NAME = "myDS";

    private static final Logger logger =
        Logger.getLogger(TransactionManagerSetup.class.getName());

    protected final Context context = new InitialContext();
    protected final PoolingDataSource datasource;
    public final DatabaseProduct databaseProduct;

    public TransactionManagerSetup(DatabaseProduct databaseProduct) throws Exception {
        this(databaseProduct, null);
    }

    public TransactionManagerSetup(DatabaseProduct databaseProduct,
                                   String connectionURL) throws Exception {

        logger.fine("Starting database connection pool");

        logger.fine("Setting stable unique identifier for transaction recovery");
        TransactionManagerServices.getConfiguration().setServerId("myServer1234");

        logger.fine("Disabling JMX binding of manager in unit tests");
        TransactionManagerServices.getConfiguration().setDisableJmx(true);

        logger.fine("Disabling transaction logging for unit tests");
        TransactionManagerServices.getConfiguration().setJournal("null");

        logger.fine("Disabling warnings when the database isn't accessed in a transaction");
        TransactionManagerServices.getConfiguration().setWarnAboutZeroResourceTransaction(false);

        logger.fine("Creating connection pool");
        datasource = new PoolingDataSource();
        datasource.setUniqueName(DATASOURCE_NAME);
        datasource.setMinPoolSize(1);
        datasource.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        datasource.setPreparedStatementCacheSize(10);

        // Our locking/versioning tests assume READ COMMITTED transaction
        // isolation. This is not the default on MySQL InnoDB, so we set
        // it here explicitly.
        datasource.setIsolationLevel("READ_COMMITTED");

        // Hibernate's SQL schema generator calls connection.setAutoCommit(true)
        // and we use auto-commit mode when the EntityManager is in suspended
        // mode and not joined with a transaction.
        datasource.setAllowLocalTransactions(true);

        logger.info("Setting up database connection: " + databaseProduct);
        this.databaseProduct = databaseProduct;
        databaseProduct.configuration.configure(datasource, connectionURL);

        logger.fine("Initializing transaction and resource management");
        datasource.init();
    }

    public Context getNamingContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public UserTransaction getUserTransaction() {
        try {
            return (UserTransaction) getNamingContext()
                .lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        try {
            return (DataSource) getNamingContext().lookup(DATASOURCE_NAME);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void rollback() {
        UserTransaction tx = getUserTransaction();
        try {
            if (tx.getStatus() == Status.STATUS_ACTIVE ||
                tx.getStatus() == Status.STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK)
                tx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Rollback of transaction failed, trace follows!");
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        logger.fine("Stopping database connection pool");
        datasource.close();
        TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager().shutdown();
    }

}
```

Message class

```
@Entity
public class Message{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String text;

    public Message(){}

    public String getText(){
        return this.text;
    }    
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

Main class

```
public class HelloWorldJPA {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HelloWorldPU");

            TransactionManagerSetup TM = null;
            try {
                TM = new TransactionManagerSetup(DatabaseProduct.MYSQL);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldJPA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            UserTransaction tx = TM.getUserTransaction();
            try {
                tx.begin();
            } catch (NotSupportedException | SystemException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldJPA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

            Message message = new Message();
            message.setText("Hello World!");

            em.persist(message);

            tx.commit();

            em.close();
        } catch (HeuristicMixedException | HeuristicRollbackException | IllegalStateException | RollbackException | SecurityException | SystemException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldJPA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Persistence.xml

```
<persistence
    version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="HelloWorldPU">
        <jta-data-source>myDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.mycompany.persistencewithhibernate.Message</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>




        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Exceptions

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at com.mycompany.persistencewithhibernate.HelloWorldJPA.main(HelloWorldJPA.java:20)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:770)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:797)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [myDS]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(InitialContext.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:118)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Try running your main app with "-Djava.naming.factory.initial=bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixInitialContextFactory"

Comment: @RainerMontag Am using netbeans. Is there a possiblity to add this option to it?

Comment: It is a really crazy configuration for a simply task :) And you catch an exception on `tx.begin()` but do nothing to rollback a transaction or properly close `em` on an exception.

Comment: I'm not using Netbeans; should be something like Properties -> Run -> JVM Options.